# Odd Suhosin memory alerts

Tags: php, memory-usage

I am getting a lot of odd suhosin alerts in my syslog. The following are example entries:

```
Jun  9 08:46:11 suhosin[9764]: ALERT - script tried to increase memory_limit to 2145386496 bytes which is above the allowed value (attacker '157.55.39.180', file '/var/www/site/index.php')  
Jun  9 08:46:11 suhosin[9744]: ALERT - script tried to increase memory_limit to 2145386496 bytes which is above the allowed value (attacker '109.74.2.136', file '/var/www/site/test.php')
Jun  9 08:46:13 suhosin[9779]: ALERT - script tried to increase memory_limit to 0 bytes which is above the allowed value (attacker 'REMOTE_ADDR not set', file 'unknown')  
Jun  9 08:46:13 suhosin[9779]: ALERT - script tried to increase memory_limit to 2145386496 bytes which is above the allowed value (attacker 'REMOTE_ADDR not set', file 'unknown')
```

What is happening here? Why 0 bytes or 2145386496 bytes (2046 GB!!??)? Why does it sometimes state the attacker and the requested script and sometimes state 'REMOTE_ADDR not set' and file 'unknown'? How do I proceed to figure this out?

Comment: 2145386496 bytes ~ 2GB

Comment: I think some part of your application increases the PHP memory limit to 2GB. Suhosin is just alerting you to this. It's not an error. The remote address is just the machine that initiated the request that called the script which tries to allocate more memory. Suhosin has flagged it as it could be part of an attack where a rogue script allocates all the machine's memory to itself causing the server to either crash or thrash the swap space, grinding to a halt. Read this: http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.memory_limit

Comment: You might want to configure that setting in the link if your app is legitimately trying to increase the memory limit, as suhosin prevented the increase which if legit could have caused your script to fail.

Comment: My memory_limit is set to 8192M and my suhosin.memory_limit is set to 4096M, effectively setting the memory cap to 4096, right?

Comment: I am guessing that `'REMOTE_ADDR not set'` means that the incoming request did not specify where to send the reply? Is this correct? If so, does this indicate some kind of DOS?

Comment: I am also guessing that `file 'unknown'`means that suhosin does not know which script was called. How can i figure out the name of the offending script?

Comment: REMOTE_ADDR won't be set if the script is run from localhost. As there's no remote address involved, could be a cron job or something. Yes that'll cap the memory limit at 4GB, but you'd want to either up that, or lower the php.ini memory limit.